# How to display text in imageview that contains image

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I am not sure of best way of explaining this but I'll try my best, what I want to do is have an ImageView that has an image and a number inside that changes based on the results in my database.

I have a function in my app that allows users to +1 films they like and when ever people +1 a film the result is send to my database, I want a way of displaying this back to the user with a ImageView that has number of +1s in the database, something along the lines of;

[image]
[image]

I am not exactly sure what this is called or if there is such feature in android, after several attempts of searching for an answer I couldn’t find anything of much use, so any help would be great! Similarly, I am sure this is not the best way of showing what I want, so if there is better idea you think I can use, please let me know.

I hope I have made myself clear, if not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer everyone, very helpful and I learned alot, one question I have is, how can I postion the text, for example to top left of the image?

Comment: nake a custom `ImageView` and override its `onDraw` method, then you can place your text anywhere you want

Comment: could to please give me an example? never came across onDraw before, however, I will look in to it myself aswell

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and  in particular [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#draw)

Answer (score 2):

you can set image and text both in one Textview

```
// image as Backgound of textview 
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
```

and

```
// text display of same textview 
textView.setText(yourstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

In RelativeLayout views can be on top of each other. The view that is the last is on top of others. You can put your image on the bottom and text on top of it. Really simple solution would be to use something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="your_image_here"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:text="your number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative layout like-------

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="Manish"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest workaround without overriding anything would be to have a TextView and set its background with a drawable resource

> 1) you can make this image with text. 2) you can set background(this
>   image) for textview.

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
// setting gravity to "center"
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
t.setText("FOO");
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: refer to OP's images. how will you precisely control text's position?

Comment: i was suggesting ways to do that @pskink

Answer (score 0):

Use a FrameLayout. Basically, can have the text go over the image giving it an impression that the text is in the image.

Another way is to simply set one layout with the background being an image, and then adding a TextView layout inside the first layout.

Lastly, just create a TextView layout and set its background to an image.